# How to check if file is currently existing using os.path

Tags: python

I am currently having a problem while checking if a file name entered by user already exists. This is the code that i am currently running, however when i run the code properly and go to save the data with a name that already exists. It prints the correct error caption "This file already exists" and returns them back to the menu of the program. I was wondering how i could have it. Is there a way so the program can ask the user to re-input the file name again?

```
if Menuchoice =='4':
    if popJuveniles ==0:
        print("please take part in option 1 before running option 4")
    else:
        if csvdata ==1:
            print("please take part in option 3 before trying to save the file")
        else:
            import csv
            #file_name=input("What would you like to call your file?")
            filename1=input("what would you like to call your file?")
    if os.path.isfile(filename1):
        print("This file already exists")
        csvext='.csv'
        filename=filename1+csvext

        with open(filename,'a') as genfile:
                insects_writer = csv.writer(genfile)
                insects_writer.writerow(csvdata)
```

Comment: can u put a while loop and ask the user

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick answer, I would use a `while` loop until the name is correct.

For example:

```
while os.path.isfile(filename1):
    print("This file already exists")
    filename1=input("what would you like to call your file?")
```

Keep in mind though that you should not use `while` very frequently for various reasons.

Comment: ok thank you, i will keep the while loop in mind when using this